# Remap Alt/Meta to L_Control (emacs-only solution acceptable)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, emacs, xmodmap

I'm looking to use the left control key as an additional [Meta] in emacs. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and I assume something could be done using `xmodmap`. Previous attempts at this have caused me to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` in order to get all of my keys working correctly again. An emacs-only solution that could go in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` would be preferable!

Answer (score 0):

```
xmodmap -pke|sed -n -e '/= Control_L/s/Control_L/Meta_L/gp' | xmodmap -
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I already have CapsLock remapped in this fashion. What I need is a way for emacs to see the left control key as my Meta key.

Comment: @user636685: Sorry, I completely misread your question.  I have now changed my answer to fit your actual question.